# sending email to multiple email address

Tags: php

i have a textarea...
i want to send emails to all of the email addresses in textarea seperated with comma....i.e

email@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com

also detect if user has type a single email address

Comment: Make very sure that this form is not publicly accessible as it can be used for sending spam!

Comment: Crowd sourcing? What have you tried?

Comment: What if the user did not enter any email address, have you worked out how to test for that? Actually, there's very little to work with from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your textarea input string is $s, then you could

```
$a = explode(',', preg_replace('/[,;\s]+/', ',', $s));
```

to get the addresses in an array. this is tolerant of a variety of delimiters between addresses.

then use your favorite regex for validating email addresses on each element of $a to select those that appear acceptable.

and then you can send each one an email or put them all as to: addresses on the one email. i use [pear::mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail).

however, the more addresses on one email, the more likely it is to be marked as spam. and consider privacy: do you want each recipient to see all recipients' addresses?

and as Felix mentioned, make sure spammers can't use your form.

Answer (score 3):

Use [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [Send email](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP's mail function, it will accept comma-delimited addresses. Or, you could use the explode function to get the addresses, so

`explode(',',$_REQUEST['addresses'])` would provide you an array of addresses, from which you could loop through.